# How to Prevent Entity Framework to Make all the attributes in the database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

The Entity Framework Make all the attributes as fields in the database
how to make Entity not Create one or more attributes as database Fields ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NotMapped, before the Attribute

```
[NotMapped]
public string Username{get; set;}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the C# attribute [`NotMapped`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute.aspx) which makes Entity Framework ignore the property when trying to map it to database columns.

```
[NotMapped]
public string PropertyThatShouldntBeInDatabase {get;set;}
```